# Entity Kind quota limit in App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there any limit on the number of Entity **Kinds** you can have in App Engine?

The low level datastore [ShardedCounter.java example](http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/sharded-counters-java/src/com/google/appengine/demos/shardedcounter/java/v2/ShardedCounter.java) creates a new Entity **Kind** for each counter name whereas the JDO example stores each counter in the same Entity Kind.  I like the advantage of the former, but don't know whether it scales to millions of counter names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datastore basically works as giant `HashMap<Key-Entity>`, as the HashMap you can put unlimited numbers of key, since one key is a mix of your appId, ***Kind,*** and entity Id or name you can use unlimited number of kinds too.

Comment: Key also contains namespace and all parent keys.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why GAE would impose such a restriction, having a new kind doesn't affect special things.
So there's no such limit.
We should be able to find it on Google if it exists.