# Maximum number of KINDs in java GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I was wondering what is the maximum number of entity kinds in gae? I was trying to find the answer but no luck.

I am using shards to do some statistics. But the problem is i will get a lot of different stats with different keys.

Comment: As far as the datastore is concerned a Kind is just one part of the key.  I don't believe there are any instrinsic limitations on the number of kinds.  Where you will run into limitations will be indexes.  You only have a limited number of indexes.  Each property of each kind normally has a default index. But you can suppress index creation for all properties if you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Kind quota limit in App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536958/entity-kind-quota-limit-in-app-engine)